# Visual studio 2015 update 2 Installed older SDK for universal app

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal

I installed the update and since then i got problems with my projects.
It says that a object is defined in a assembly but is not referenced.
I believe it to be windows.foundation.
see below for the errors(top part image).
https://www.flickr.com/photos/141471080@N02/26099716161

Edit: for the first part in case you can't read it.
https://www.flickr.com/photos/141471080@N02/25563697643

I get these errors in newly created projects as well.

I figured out that it installed the sdk 10.0.10586.0 with the update.
While i however was using the sdk 10.0.26624 previously.
So i tried reinstalling the 10.0.26624 again.
it says it is already installed while in "programs and features" you can see it’s not. The older SDK is however listed there(middle part image).

I tried searching for it. No luck there as the windows search can’t find it.
I tried searching it myself and i believe this is the location where it should be located but isn’t there(bottom part image).

I tried the repair function with no luck.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: I would suggest you to modify/repair VS 2105 installation, remember to select 10240 SDK. And last way to fix it is reinstall VS 2015

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already tried the repair and i'm trying the modify now. I have a app that was build with the 26624 sdk. Will this cause problems if i use 10240 sdk? Isn't there a way to get the 26624 sdk anyway. I find it odd that the installer doesn't give me the option to download the newest sdk(26624).

Comment: newest production SDK is 10586, I think you are using 26624 as a preview SDK. Note that VS 2015 installer only list 10240 and 10586 as installation options.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it now.

Comment: No luck, i'm going to do a clean install. I hope this will work. Also they should have added the preview as well and say preview next to it.

Comment: Yesss, i got it working again after countless repairs/modify's en clean installs.